# How to calculate R for an AC load on a 3-ph system

Tags: resistors, ac, three-phase, load, ohms-law

I'm trying to calculate the resistors in an AC dummy load for a 3-ph system.

A simplified schematic can be found below. The idea is to switch (with regular AC 1-ph contactors) some resistors on each phase, the middle point being the neutral point.

The generator has a line-to-line Voltage of 280V and we're trying to dissipate a maximum of 60kW.

I'm using the following formula : I = P/(sqrt(3)*U) = 60000/(sqrt(3)*280) = 123A

==> I'm trying to have 123A per phase in order to dissipate 60kW.

R=U/I = 2,276 Ohms
==> Am I correct in assuming I have to have a 20kW resistor of this value on each phase? (of course divided between several resistors in order to be able to reach intermediate power values via the contactors).

Thanks for the input!

[image]

Comment: Yes, your math is correct.

Comment: Your diagram shows you have grounded all 3 phases  on both sides of the load.  This is not how you create a wye point.

Comment: Hi KH7, yes indeed, bad schematic on my side.
I guess you got the idea behind it which is that the middle point of the wye is the return path for the resistor loads.
Will correct the schematic ASAP.

Comment: @K H : Updated the schematic, is that more like it?

Comment: Yes, the schematic is better.  I'm assuming three phase contactors.  I'd recommend spreading loads out and adding some form of cooling.

Comment: Of course, the resistors will be fan-cooled.
One thing I'm unsure about is how should I fan-out (no pun intended) the resistors on the 3 phases :
I.E : say I want, 60 "steps" to full-power, I'll multiply the 2,276ohms by 60 and switch on or off all these resistors in // Now, I effectively have to put a resistor of R=2,276/60 * 3  on each phase in order to have these 60 steps, am I correct?